# XMLHttpRequest not working on button click null

Tags: html, jquery, xmlhttprequest

I have a page and when I click on this page with "trigger" I can print the "#content" page. but I want it to return to the "home" I want with the "BACK" button on the page that comes up, but it just doesn't work. Where am I making the mistake?

index.php

```
<div class="app-content content" id="content">
<?php require 'home' ?></div>
```

home.php

```
<div id="kasaButton">
    <a type="button" href="#" data-target="contact"> Contact</a>
    <a type="button" href="#" data-target="gallery"> Gallery</a>
</div>

<div class="card">
<table class="datatables-basic table">
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>İD</th>
        <th>NAME</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr>
        <td>İD</td>
        <td>NAME</td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

gallery

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari Adı" value=""/>
        <button id="save" type="submit">SAVE</button>
        <button id="back" type="button">BACK</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var trigger = $("#kasaButton a"),
            container = $("#content");

        trigger.on("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            target = $this.data('target');
            container.load(target);
            return false;
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#back").on("click", function () {
            $("#content").load('home');
        });
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

Just add a div with the id of "content"
here is an example of **gallery.php:**

```
<div class="card-body">
    <form action="" method="post">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Cari Adı" value=""/>
        <button id="save" type="submit">SAVE</button>
        <button id="back" type="button">BACK</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div id="content"></div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
        var trigger = $("#kasaButton a"),
            container = $("#content");

        trigger.on("click", function () {
            var $this = $(this)
            target = $this.data('target');
            container.load(target);
            return false;
        });
    });

$(document).ready(function () {
        $("#back").on("click", function () {
            $("#content").load('home.php');
        });
    })
</script>
```

Comment: I don't say it that way. When I click the button on the incoming page, "home.php" will open again

Comment: What "incoming page" do you specifically mean?